# How to use Semantic UI removable icon

Tags: jquery, icons, semantic-ui, removable

Semantic UI haven't documented how the removable widget works.

[image: Below is an example of what I mean]

The small x icon is what I mean by removable. What is the Semantic UI call I need to get this to make this work so that when I click on the small x it removes that element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do this manually using the following function:

```
var removeParent = function(e) {
    $(e).parent().remove();
};
```

Then in my HTML I added an onclick event to the element and passed in `this`.

```
<div class="ui huge label" style="margin: 7px"> 
    <i class="edit icon"></i> 
    <i class="delete icon" onclick="removeParent(this)"></i>
</div>
```

Answer taken from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814805/remove-parent-without-an-id-or-class-using-jquery)